# Adding raw Data to the encoder

Tags: swift, serialization

I have an `Encodable` struct that contains raw `Data`. This data is expected to be a raw representation of a JSON string.

When I encode this struct, I expect the encoding to have that `Data` be part of the struct's JSON object.

Here's the playground I have come up with so far, with outlined **expected** and **actual** results:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Payload: Encodable {
    let name: String
    let contents: Data

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case contents
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(contents, forKey: .contents)
    }
}

let payload = Payload(
    name: "Hello",
    
    /// Integers corresponding to ASCII values of a valid JSON string: `{"text":"C"}`
    contents:Data([123, 34, 116, 101, 120, 116, 34, 58, 34, 67, 34, 125])
)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let data = try encoder.encode(payload)

let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
print(string)

/// expected: `{"name":"Hello","contents": {"text":"C"} }`
/// actual: `{"name":"Hello","contents":"eyJ0ZXh0IjoiQyJ9"}`
```

I have also tried to encode `contents` as a `String`, but that results in:

```
{"name":"Hello","contents":"{\"text\":\"C\"}"}
```

Which is close, but still not what I want

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/2895381-dataencodingstrategy It's base 64, as it's a `Data`. The encoder see `contents` value, and it encoded it as `Data`, so with Base64 encoding.

Comment: Will this work if I manage to convert `contents` to a base16 (hex) array and encode each of the values separately? Something tells me it will just encode it as a string. I think the fundamental problem is there's no way to add raw data to `Encoder`, which is what I'm trying to do at the end of the day

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, as shown in the example code, to encode and then recover your `Payload` contents `Data` as a `String`. Use the same approach for non-SwiftUI systems:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var payloadContents = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(payloadContents)
            .onAppear {
                
                let payload = Payload(
                    name: "Hello",
                    /// Integers corresponding to ASCII values of a valid JSON string: `{"text":"C"}`
                    contents: Data([123, 34, 116, 101, 120, 116, 34, 58, 34, 67, 34, 125])
                )

               // direct access
               // payloadContents = payload.stringContents!

                do {
                    // encode the payload
                    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(payload)

                    // decode the payload
                    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Payload.self, from: data)
                    print("\n---> decoded: \(decoded)")  // <-- raw data
                    
                    // get the `contents` to the desired String
                    payloadContents = String(data: decoded.contents, encoding: .utf8)!
            
                    // alternative
                    // payloadContents = decoded.stringContents!

                    print("\n---> payloadContents: \(payloadContents)\n")
                    
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
    }
}


struct Payload: Codable {  // <-- here
    let name: String
    let contents: Data
    
    var stringContents: String? {
        String(data: contents, encoding: .utf8)  // <-- here
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, contents
    }
}
```